# Why can't I print anything with __toString() in PHP?

Tags: php, tostring, magic-methods

I've created a class with a constructor and a toString method but it's not working.

```
class Course
{
    protected $course
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->$course = "hello";
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $string = (string) $this->$course;
        return $string;
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property
```

if I just do:

```
$string = (string) $course;
```

Nothing prints out.

I'm new to magic methods in PHP though I'm familiar with Java's toString method.

Comment: I think you meant for the title to read "can't."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there is a little typo in your constructor, it should be:

```
protected $course;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->course = "hello"; // I added $this->
}
```

if you now call your `__toString()` function it will print "hello".

**Update**
You should change the `__toString()` function like this:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->course;
}
```

Your total code would become this: (go copy paste :) )

```
class Course
{
    protected $course;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->course = "hello";
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->course;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same Fatal error: Cannot access empty property error but now it's referring to the line in the constructor.

Comment: `$this->$course` in the _toString method would only work if there's a local `$course` variable in that method, so the code's still broken. But +1 for catching the constructor error. Between you and haltabush, you've fixed the problem.

Comment: @MarcB added the suggested `__ToString()` to make my answer complete.

Answer (score 7):

You've understood the magic method all right, but you have an error here : $course is not defined.

Your error is on this line:

```
    $string = (string) $this-> $course;
```

It should be

```
    $string = (string) $this->course;
```

You might know that in PHP you can do something like this:

```
$course='arandomproperty';
$string = $this->$course; //that equals to $this->arandomproperty
```

Here, $course is not defined, so it defaults to '' (and throw a NOTICE error, which you should display or log at least during development)

---

Edit:
You also have an eror in you constructor, you should do `$this->course='hello';`

---

edit 2

Here is a working code. Is there is something you don't understand here?

```
<?php
class Course
{
    protected $course;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->course = "hello";
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $string = (string) $this->course;
        return $string;
    }
}
$course = new Course();
echo $course;
```

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions but it still doesn't work :( I really don't understand.

Comment: Get rid of the `$this->$course` and replace it by `$this->course`

Comment: when you say "nothing prints out" maybe you're not using print or echo? Try echo (string)$course;

Comment: OH, I see now. I added the dollar sign!

Comment: As I mentionned in my initial post, you should display or log (if you watch the logs :p ) all PHP errors, it will help you during debugging :)